# How to get all changes you made to your config files (since system install) in one shot?

Tags: linux, loops, diff, configuration-files

I wonder if there is any way i could retrieve all changes i made to my various configuration files since install(residing in /etc and so on) in one shot?

I imagine some kind of loop, that uses 'diff' to compare all those files to a 'standard installation' of ubuntu. Output should be a single file with information regarding the changes that were made and a timestamp.

Perhaps there is even a way to put all that in a script and let it run regularly to automatically keep track of future config file changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are already modified, I guess your only option is to `diff` your files with a fresh install. Keep in mind some files might be specific to you computer, I'm thinking of files that can hold device-specific values like your mac address `udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, your drives uuid `/etc/fstab`, etc.

If you're planning this ahead, there are at least two options you can consider:

1. use a VCS such as git.
2. use a filesystem that keeps a complete history of the changes made.

Comment: For the *perfect* solution for keeping `/etc` under version control, look into  [etckeeper](http://etckeeper.branchable.com/). It hooks into the package managers (apt-get, yum, dnf) and automatically records configuration changes that programs do during updates for instance.